# No ClassTag available for Vec[Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-breeze

I am kind of new to scala and spark. Now I would like to generate a vector on each of the worker. When I use this line, I got two errors:

```
val b = sc.parallelize(1 to n, n).map( i => DenseVector[Double]](10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0))
```

1. `No ClassTag available for Vec[Double]`
2. `not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Vec[Double]])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Vec[Double]]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$3.`

Could anybody help me on this?

Comment: I believe there are lots of Syntax errors in that one line. Fix them and then may be we can help.

Comment: The full signature of parrallelize function is `def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T] ` ... See that implicit parameter. You need to create an implicit instance of ClassTag for respective Type.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am confused by the generic vector in scala and the vector in breeze package. It should be written in this way:                                       val b = sc.parallelize(1 to 4, 4).map( i => (10,20,30,40).asInstanceOf[DenseVector[Double]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works for me

```
scala> import breeze.linalg._
scala> val n = 2
n: Int = 2
scala> val b = sc.parallelize(1 to n, n).map( i => DenseVector[Double](10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0))
b: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:24
```

Here is some data in the rdd:

```
   scala> b.take(1)
res1: Array[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]] = Array(DenseVector(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0))
```

Comment: The syntax is different in Mllib and breeze. I use breeze.

Comment: ahh correction accepted.  I put your breeze code in the spark-shell and it works.

Comment: lol. I write it in this way "(10,20,30,40).asInstanceOf[DenseVector[Double]]"  for a simple type conversion.